# How Can I convert this JSON type to C# dictionary

Tags: c#, json

```
        HI guys the problem is Solved with the Help Of David. I dint use his method but used Just these TWo Lines of Code. And It Works. I am Editing the Question, Which Has the Solution For this.
        I am trying to convert this JSON string to C# Dictionary<string, string> I tried several methods but no success. I want to access them as Key value pair but I cant figure out How to convert this type of JSOn with data member.

            {
              "d": "{
                \"USD\":\"0.793302\",
                \"USVCAD\":\"1.260554\",
                \"EUR\":\"0.642978\",
                \"EUVCAD\":\"1.555264\",
                \"GBP\":\"0.557200\",
                \"GBVCAD\":\"1.794687\",
                \"INR\":\"51.777115\",
                \"INVCAD\":\"0.019314\",
                \"AUD\":\"1.021391\",
                \"AUVCAD\":\"0.979057\",
                \"SPD\":\"1.040986\",
                \"SPVCAD\":\"0.960628\",
                \"SWF\":\"0.763388\",
                \"SWVCAD\":\"1.309949\",
                \"MAL\":\"3.078805\",
                \"MAVCAD\":\"0.324801\",
                \"YEN\":\"85.144672\",
                \"YEVCAD\":\"0.011745\",
                \"YUA\":\"4.975648\",
                \"YUVCAD\":\"0.200979\"
              }"
            }

I used the following code to get the above string from Browser. But when I access the Key after Serializing I get the Key as "d" and item.Value as all the Values. I want to access value for each item like USD. But when i try to call item.Value it returns string with all the values
```

These Two Lines Did the trick - David I dint have to create a separate Class to get the Value. Just used your Tip to Deserialize JSON Twice

Thank You guys for all you Help, this problem has been solved. I did not create separate class to achieve this.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                // This Will Get the JSON Content
                var json = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:51899/Service2.svc/GetCurrencyRates");


                //Deserialize the JSON String to Dictionary. This will return one Key = 'd' and many Values
                var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

                //Deserialize the Dictionary Values. This will return one Values{ Key = Value} 
                var values2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(values["d"]);

                // You need to decode JSON Twice
                MessageBox.Show(values2["USD"]);


            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: [I downvoted because your problem statement is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Please Check Now and advise

Comment: Your "JSON" is not a valid JSON string. Fix that first. You can verify your JSON on any [JSON validator](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=JSON+validator).

Comment: The JSON input is valid according to RFC 4627 (JSON specfication).

Comment: How are you validating your JSON because I checked with multiple sites and all indicate it's not valid according to RFC 4627.

Comment: I validated JSON here - https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html

Comment: The solution should be [added as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not edited into the question.

Answer (score 2):

So you have JSON encoded as a string within another JSON document, so you'll have to decode it twice to get the dictionary:

```
// Add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then:

using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Data
{
    public string d;

    static Dictionary<String, String> DecodeDictionary(string json)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonString);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(data.d);

    }
}
```

Take your JSON string and do:

```
var theDictionaryYouWant = Data.DecodeDictionary(jsonString);
```